# Should I edit an overly complicated question that already has answers or delete it?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188855/how-do-i-configure-rest-urls-when-running-react-with-azure-api-management/57190273) that in retrospect should have been multiple questions.

For example,

- How to configure multiple environments in JavaScript
- What should the URL be when using APIM
- How do I configure the routing in APIM

However, before I came to this realisation, people have already answered the question.

The answers are only for the first part and don't go into enough detail to be good answers.

This [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189976/how-do-i-build-for-a-uat-environment-using-react) has generated better answers to the first part.

If I edit the original question to only focus on the APIM part it will make the existing answers look weird and out of place.

Should I delete the question instead?

Comment: You can't delete that question, as is. It has more than one answer, and one of them is upvoted. Either of those criteria by itself would prevent deletion.